# Symfony2 lock full site with firewall

Tags: security, symfony, authentication, roles

I would like to close my full site and only access to authenticated users, but I would like to keep some routes to public. Public routes would be:

/

/news

/registration

All otheres are locked.
I've made a firewall which looks like this:

```
firewalls:
    user_login:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~

    user_area:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            login_path: _main_index #this is a route to /
        logout:
            path: _main_logout #this is a route to /logout
            target: _main_index #this is a route to /
            invalidate_session: false

access_control:
    - { path: ^/news, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/registration, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/user-panel, roles: ROLE_ACTIVE_USER } #is this neccessary?
```

Then when I'm logging in to a restricted area (/user-panel) it sais I need to fully authenticate myself.

I store my roles in security.yml, not in database.

I hope you can help me! Thank you very much!

EDIT:
My loginCheckAction looks like this::

```
        $encodedPassword = $this->get('user.user_service')->generatePasswordHash($user, $request->request->get('_password'));
        if ($user->getPassword() == $encodedPassword) {
            $user->setLastLoginOn(new \DateTime());
            $this->em->user($rocker);
            $this->em->flush();

            $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'user_area', array($user->getRoles()));

            $request->getSession()->set('_security_user_area', serialize($token));

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_user_panel'));
        }
```

Comment: Why two firewalls with the same pattern? this won't work

Comment: I dont know how this exactly work, but if i delete the user_login section, the site dont even call the loginCheckAction...

Comment: I've got this. user_login needs to log in automatically (otherwise you need to implement UserProviderInterface). user_area is actually the firewall which close the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, one of the major problem was the multiple firewall on the same route.

Symfony uses /login route to login, /login_check to check credentials and /logout to log out by default. For me, all routes was good, except the login route, because I wanted to log in users from / route.

Because of this, I had to implement UserProviderInterface into my UserRepository like this: [Authenticating Someone with a Custom Entity Provider - Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#authenticating-someone-with-a-custom-entity-provider)

I just modified this on my way (I user email as username).

Logincheck and logout is working automatically, because I use the default routes.

And for all of this, you have to implement AdvancedUserInterface to Users entity!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an catch-all firewall that requires authentication, like this:

```
   - { path: ^/,                   roles: ROLE_ACTIVE_USER }
```

That will make all pages that aren't explicitely listed to be accessible without authentication (i.e. with IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY) inaccessible. However, since you didn't list your homepage yet, you'll need to add that too.

```
   - { path: ^/$,                  roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Make sure to put it above the catch-all entry, as Symfony processes entries from top to bottom, and stops when it found a matching entry.

Comment: If I put this line

`- { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`

then this line

`- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ACTIVE_USER }`

I will get an 500 alert error, and my profiler didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow anonymus token

```
user_area:
    pattern: ^/
    form_login:
        login_path: _main_index #this is a route to /
    logout:
        path: _main_logout #this is a route to /logout
        target: _main_index #this is a route to /
        invalidate_session: false
    anonymous: ~
```

Comment: I did, but nothing new... :(

Comment: whats happen then you go to `/news`?

Comment: this part is ok now, thx to mirk, but i got another problem :) check out my edit section in my first post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/registration, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/news, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/(css|js), roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/(_wdt|_profiler), roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ACTIVE_USER }
```

I think  **login_check** is used internally by the symfony security system just like **logout**. This empty function should work.

```
/**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
 */
public function loginCheckAction()
{

}
```

If  you want to redirect the user to the panel route after successful login you need to implement login event listener. Symfony documentation  [How to create an Event Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html).

Some resources for symfony loginlistener.

http://www.ens.ro/2012/03/14/symfony2-login-event-listener/

https://gist.github.com/smottt/1075753

Comment: This could be good, profiler error is came up no more! THX!

BUT!

Check out my EDIT section in my main post. I pasted my loginCheckAction.

When I log in, it sais i need fully authenticate myself, but if I check the session in the profiler, I can see those datas which I need to authenticate myself.

So it looks like i'm not authenticated correctly...